# Error while httpd restart

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

My httpd.conf file contains following configurations

```
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
#SSLPassPhraseDialog  exec:/root/passphrase.sh
```

when the line containing automatic reading of Passphrase is commented it works fine.

But when i change it to

```
#SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLPassPhraseDialog  exec:/root/passphrase.sh
```

it fails, just with a failed message.

contents of passphrase file

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "xyz123"
```

Comment: did you check if the script is executable chmod +x /root/passphrase.sh

Comment: @knowky the script was not in executable mode, i made the required changes and it ran. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check rights permissions of passphrase file.

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes for this.

- Some times users put the passphrase-script under `/etc/httpd/conf.d`
  directory. Don't do that.
- Some time that script need to have `execute` `(chmod +x)` permission.
- May be `/bin/bash` doesn't work with the current Linux distro then you have to include `/bin/sh`.